# How to make child element to expand horizontally parent element when overflowed?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent container with a child. When child is overflowed horizontally (i.e. bigger than browser window) it does not affect a parent. Is there any solution for parent to adjust width according to child if child is wider?

As a result both may be wider than screen, and I am OK with that.
I am not using any UI library (no bootstrap, etc.) If child is smaller than screen, both should adjust width to browser window.

```html
<div style="border: 2px solid red">
    <div style="border: 2px solid blue; width:2000px">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the display of the outer div to inline-block:

```html
<div style="border: 2px solid red;display:inline-block">
    <div style="border: 2px solid blue; width:2000px">test</div>
</div>
```

If you need to have both fill the screen when the child is less than the width of the screen, then both need min-width:100% and box-sizing:border-box (and you can remove the display-inline-block from the parent):

```css
div {
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 2px solid red;">
  <div style="border: 2px solid blue; width:300px">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: By the way, you forgot about `min-width`.

Comment: `min-width` won't keep the parent width equal to the child width if the child width changes. unless both have a `min-width` which is more code, and less elegant

Comment: @ErnestTen - I'm not sure if that's what the OP needs, but I updated my answer to include code that will do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could set `display: inline-block` to parent and `min-width: 100%` to both parent and child.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w9dcu79s/2/).